# Linux program creates directory but then can not access it

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm having an issue with a program that is making a call to mkdir(2). The program is able to create and remove directories without any issue but when I try to call chdir I keep getting access denied errors. The shell is also only able to call rmdir on the directory (its access is also denied). My call to mkdir is as follows:

```
mkdir(&message[sizeof(size_t) + commandType.size() + 1], S_IRWXO | S_IREAD | S_IWRITE)
```

The flags might be overkill but I couldn't get anything to allow this process to access the directory it created. At the end of the day the creating process is the only one that really needs to access the new directory, but it would be more convenient for me if everyone could.

Comment: Can you check the owner of the created directory?

Comment: What is your `umask` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `S_IRWXU` in the flags to `mkdir` (to give user access), you might want `S_IRWXG` to let group access...

Remember that a directory should be executable to be able to search inside it